# Extending tangent vectors to commuting vector fields on a neighborhood

Tags: fiber-bundles

$M$ is a manifold, $X$ and $Y$ are tangent vectors in $T_xM$. Is it always possible to extend $X$ and $Y$ to local vector fields $U$ and $V$ around $x$ so that $[U,V]=0$ hold on some neighborhood of $x$? Or at least a weaker version: so that $[U,V]=0$ at $x$.

This arises from `note 1` in the Wikipedia `Exterior covariant derivative` article, where some special tangent vectors are extended to special commuting vector fields using some specific construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for simplicity that $M$ is 2-dimensional, and that $X$ and $Y$ are linearly independent.  Choose coordinates $(u,v)$ in a neighborhood of the point $x$ in such a way that *at the point*, one has $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and $Y=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$.  Since the coordinate vector *fields* $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial}{\partial v}$ always commute, we thereby obtain the necessary extension $U=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and similarly for $V$.  In  higher dimension the argument is similar.